# Cocoon (Ruby Gem) not working in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I am currently developing an application with Ruby on Rails and am trying to implement nested attributes with the cocoon gem: With my current configurations it works on my local machine, but not in production on my server. I have ideas why it does not work, but not how to fix it.

First, here is my manifest that includes cocoon:

```
application.js    

...
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require chartkick
//= require_tree .
```

I see the problem here: Cocoon is before jquery and jquery_ujs, therefore I get  the following error in the console of the developer tools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at cocoon.self-6874ad698cefd21cc1119b773550f61b5c1a60396460f015222af59293affe80.js?body=1:131

Even though I have the error, locally the nested attributes still work. In production on the other hand, the button to add the association (*link_to_add_association*) does not work anymore (it is clickable, but does nothing, not even throwing an error). Of course **I also tried to rearrange the manifest and put jquery and jquery_ujs before cocoon**: But then cocoon does not work properly anymore: Instead of inserting one element with *link_to_add_association*, cocoon inserts two.

This is the head of my application.html:

```
application.html.erb

..
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'chartkick' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
..
```

Here are relevant parts of my Gemfile (ruby 2.3.1p112 is installed on the production server):

```
Gemfile

..
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.2.2'

..
# Used for the dynamic forms:
gem 'simple_form', '3.4.0'
gem 'cocoon', '1.2.9'

..
```

I have no idea why cocoon inserts entries twice or why the application does not work in production. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Other question: You include chartkick.js in application.js, but then you also load chartkick in your layout here `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'chartkick' %>` . That doesnt make sense to me

Comment: ANd why dont you move cocoon below the jquery requires ?

Comment: @SimonFranzen Your first answer solved my problem. Thank you, so much! If you put "only reference chartkick once" in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear. Yes I updated my answer @megahra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only reference chartkick once

remove line `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'chartkick' %>` from your layout

Comment: @megahra updated my answer. Let's clean up and remove both comments under this post

Answer (score 0):

You include the `application.js` twice, this means that the cocoon javascript is also included twice, so there will be two click-handlers for cocoon:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'chartkick' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Imho you should just delete the first line.